# Handlebars partial with dynamic partial location

Tags: handlebars.js

I need to compile a Handlebars partial on init through a JS file and I'm getting the error "the partial two-column could not be found". I don't know where Handlebars is looking for the partial and I can't change the app structure as I don't own that segment.

Is there a way to tell Handlebars where to look for the partial on compile or another step of the partial process?

Folder structure:

```
root
|- js
|   -script.js
|
|- template
    - partials
      - two-column.hbs
    - main.hbs
```

Script.js

```
function getPartial(partialName, partialData) {
    const templateString= `${Handlebars.compile(`{{> ${partialName} data}}`)({data: partialData})}`;
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(`${safeString}`);
};

let content = getPartial(`two-column`, {title: 'my title', content: 'my content'});
```

How do I direct Handlebars to look in my partials folder for the two-column.hbs file?

Comment: Are your Handlebars templates executed on the client or on the server? It is unclear to me as the `.hbs` files would suggest to me that this is a Node JS (server-side) application, but the script.js file looks like something loaded client-side.

Comment: It's a custom framework server side using a flavor of react. This file runs client-side, after the DOM is loaded as part of a callback on event listener click.

Comment: If you are trying to execute a partial client-side then that partial code, along with a Handlebars.registerHelper call, will need to be included in the JavaScript running in the browser.